# Selecting multiple files with in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to use Scriptreplay with multiple log/timing files located in the same Directory.

The script I have right now looks like this:

```bsh
select timings in /mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/*; 
do
clear
scriptreplay $timings 
done;;
esac
```

Is there a way to select two files (the log and the timingfile of that log) at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is if you can get there from the filename. For instance, if the selected filename is `/mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/20140326.log`, you could get to another file in the same directory with a different extension, or another file in another directory pretty easily.

Let's first look at stripping the extension off:

```
timings="/mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/20140326.timing" # just for testing
log="${timings%%.*}.log"
echo $log
```

And here's how to strip the leading path to change to a different directory:

```
log="/mnt/home/$USER/timings/${timings##*/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

OP wrote:

> It works great!!!
>
> ```
> select timings in /mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/*.timing; 
> do
> log="${timings%%.*}.log"
>   clear
>   echo "${txtred}Script gestartet${txtrst}"
>   scriptreplay $timings $log
>   echo "${txtred}Script beendet${txtrst}"
> done;;
> esac
> ```